# Unwanted Rewrite in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, rewriting

I've got an app on the backend of my site that is having issues being accessed. The site itself uses .htaccess for routing purposes, but I seem to have my rules incorrect or something. I'm basically trying to route everything that does not contain the directory `tools/` or `ajax/` to `index.php`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# the folders mentioned here will be accessible and not rewritten
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/(ajax|tools)/
# but rewrite everything else
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# UTF-8 encoding
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Use UTF-8 encoding for anything served text/plain or text/html
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

# Force UTF-8 for a number of file formats
AddCharset utf-8 .atom .css .js .json .rss .vtt .xml

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# A little more security
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# "-Indexes" will have Apache block users from browsing folders without a
# default document Usually you should leave this activated, because you
# shouldn't allow everybody to surf through every folder on your server (which
# includes rather private places like CMS system folders).
<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
  Options -Indexes
</IfModule>

# Block access to "hidden" directories or files whose names begin with a
# period. This includes directories used by version control systems such as
# Subversion or Git.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
  RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]
</IfModule>

# Block access to backup and source files. These files may be left by some
# text/html editors and pose a great security danger, when anyone can access
# them.
<FilesMatch "(\.(bak|config|sql|fla|psd|ini|log|sh|inc|swp|dist)|~)$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
  Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>

# prevent access to PHP error log
<Files php_errors.log>
 Order allow,deny
 Deny from all
 Satisfy All
</Files>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access 6 hours"
</IfModule>
```

However, when attempting to run the long- executing scripts in the tools directory, it eventually gives me a fatal error saying the path ./controllers/tools.php cannot be found, meaning that the URI has been processed by the routing system when it shouldn't have been. Any thoughts?

EDIT - updated with the full .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

Have it this way:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# the folders mentioned here will be accessible and not rewritten
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/(ajax|tools)/ [NC]
# but rewrite everything else
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

`THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules. Example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`

Comment: This is working fine on my Apache. Post your complete .htaccess in question and look at your Apache `error.log` for reason of 500 error.

Comment: Updated the post. The only error I can find in the logs is "End of script output before headers"

Comment: This is the exact error in apache's error log: `[Mon Aug 20 12:27:39.060106 2018] [core:error] [pid 8471] [client 66.249.88.33:62447] End of script output before headers: player.php`. And that is all the info it gives.

Comment: No the Apache log is in my webserver's root directory as per custom configuration, and my php log is output to each individual website's root. Literally all I get is the End of script error and the Internal Server Error in the browser. The file shown there resides in the `/tools/` directory which is supposed to be safe from being rewritten

Comment: I should be able to use either https or http to access `kocbyte.axiomaticenigma.com/tools/player.php` and `kocbyte.axiomaticenigma.com/tools/scan.php`, as well as `kocbyte.axiomaticenigma.com/ajax/infoListener.php` and `kocbyte.axiomaticenigma.com/ajax/mapListener.php`, without them being routed to my controllers. The current .htaccess, shown above, causes error 500 and only produces the `end of script output before headers` error  in the apache error.log

Comment: No other .htaccess at all.

Comment: ok `curl -IL 'kocbyte.axiomaticenigma.com/tools/'` returns `403`. Can you explain how that is happening?

Comment: Can you create a file called `info.php` with this code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` inside `/tools/` directory?